# After deployment the reset password url is not working

Tags: node.js, azure, api, deployment, mern

In azure there is
`const restPasswordUrl = '${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/password/reset/${restToken}'` a link for resetpassword token and it sends the link on mail with http host but when I clicked on it it redirects to https link and then user route not found.

````
    const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found",404));
    }

    //Get ResetPassword Token
    const restToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();
    user.resetPasswordExpire = new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 minutes from now

    await user.save({validateBeforeSave:false})

   //const restPasswordUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/password/reset/${restToken}`
   const restPasswordUrl = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/password/reset/${restToken}`

    const message = `Click on the Link to change your Password :- \n\n ${restPasswordUrl} \n\n If you have not requested this email then please ignore it.`

    try {
        await sendEmail({
            email:user.email,
            subject: `Password Recovery`,
            message
        });

        res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            message: `Email sent to ${user.email} successfully`
        })

        logger.info("email sent sucessfully to change password !")
        
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Email not sent!');
        user.resetPasswordToken= undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined

        await user.save({validateBeforeSave:false})

        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message,500))
    }
})```


this is the whole code it works fine when I use FRONTEND URL in localhost
````

const restPasswordUrl = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/password/reset/${restToken}`

```
The frontend and backend both is hosted on azure
```

Answer (score 0):

So, It was because the backend and frontend was hosted on two different domains that's why  It was taking host as `backend-hosted-url` but the we need frontend url that's why I changed form

```
 const restPasswordUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/password/reset/${restToken}`
```

to this

```
   const restPasswordUrl = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/password/reset/${restToken}`
```

and added the frontend url in env configuration.